# Falcon 9 Landing Speed

Tags: spacex, rockets, falcon-9, landing

I wanted to know what the fastest speed is that a Falcon 9 can land at and thus the max force the landing legs can withstand.
I assumed the mass when landed is 26,000 kg (I once heard that somewhere). That means that when it is just standing there each leg will have (26,000 kg * 9.8 m/s^2) / 4 = 63,700 N of force on them.
I did some video analysis on the Falcon 9 flight 26 (15 June 2016). This landing failed because it ran out of propellant just before landing so it fell a few meters. I thought this could be a good estimate for just above the upper bound of landing speed. My calculations showed that it was traveling at about 30 m/s at touchdown.
Another rough estimate I made is that it takes 0.1 seconds from when the legs just touch the ground to a complete stop. That would the landing of flight 26 (26,000 kg * (30 m/s / 0.1 s)) / 4 = 1,950,000 N.
Is it reasonable to assume the the legs could survive up to 325,000 Newtons, making the max landing speed 5 m/s?

Comment: Not entirely sure why this was downvoted...

Comment: I think "plausible guess" would be more accurate.  Unless I misunderstand, you essentially took a failure case and halved it right?  15m/s sounds pretty fast for a 26 tonne machine to hit a barge and survive.  Most landings also *look* much slower than that, though my eyes have deceived me before.  Props for taking a stab at an analytical answer though!  I am pretty curious now.